# echo * | xargs -n1 echo , Is there a shorter, more elegant way of a line by line listing?

Tags: command-line, pipe, ls, xargs, echo

when I do `ls` the output is in columns, however I need the output to be in only one column, line by line, one entry per line.

So the only way I could come up with is:

```
echo * | xargs -n1 echo
```

Is this the standard way to achieve it or is this bad style?

Comment: That's what `ls -1` is for. :)

Comment: Or `ls | cat` which is NOT a UUOC though it looks like one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's bad, for all the reasons plain `xargs` is bad, namely it breaks with filenames containing whitespace or backslashes:

```
$ touch "foo bar"
$ echo * | xargs -n1 echo
foo
bar
```

Besides, it runs a copy of (the external) `echo` command for every file.

In most shells you could use `printf "%s\n" *` to get the listing. Or `ls -1`.

However, the question is, what do you want to do with the list of files? Just look at them or use them in a script? For the latter, you're probably better off using

```
for f in * ; do something with "$f" ; done
```

or some variant of `find ... -exec somecmd {} +`

Answer (score 8):

The general advice about xargs is, don't use `xargs`. Its input format is not supported by any common tool.

The next level of xargs usage is, use `xargs -0`, with input that's null-separated. But in your case, xargs is pointless anyway.

If you want to list files in a directory, you can use `ls`. To ensure that there will be a single file per line, use `ls -1`. The `ls` command always puts one file per line when its output is going to a pipe or to a file. When the output is a terminal, plain `ls` aligns file names in columns but `ls -1` doesn't.

If you have a list of words and you want to print them one per line, you can use `printf '%s\n'`. This works similarly to `echo`, except that it prints a line break after each element instead of a space and there's no danger of backslash or initial-dash processing.

```
printf '%s\n' *          # prints the names of the files in the current directory
printf '%s\n' "$@"       # prints the positional arguments
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"  # prints the element of the array `a`
```

Answer (score 3):

It will not do what you want when you have special characters in your file names:

```
$ touch 'name
with newline' 'other name\nwith newline'
$ echo * | xargs -n1 echo
name
with
newline
other
name
with
newline
```

If you just want to list the files there is `ls -1`. Otherwise use `find` with the `-exec` flag.