# Make AWK process a huge fileset with a single process

Tags: text-processing, awk, wildcards

I need to process a large subset of a large set of files with `AWK`(*) so that it accumulates a set of variables across the files.

The straighforward approach of passing multiple filenames to `AWK` with a file wildcard worked fine for a small fileset, but expectedly results in `"Argument list too long"` when run with a production-sized set of files.

**What is the best-practice approach to such a problem?**

---

Some details:

- the entire set of files is 20-50K files; a subset for a single run is 5-10K for now (but great if it could scale easily)
- I need to count occurrences of each word across a set of files, giving each file a runtime-defined weight: each word in the same file gets the same weight, but the same word occurring in different files get different weight. For each word, file weights are then added.
- therefore splitting the fileset into smaller subsets would mean aggregating intermediary results. It doesn't look very elegant, and will require to add floating points while joining several intermediary files, which makes the whole procedure even less readable and intuitive.
- another approach I can think of is to feed `awk` with an output of `find` & `cat`. What I don't like is sacrificing readability of `BEGINFILE`/`ENDFILE` and working around with parsing some delimiter between files to reset file-specific weight, counters and arrays.
- file subset to process from the current folder is provided as a separate file A; in `BEGINFILE` section I skip files that I don't need
- weight for each file X is derived from a combination of that file with a reference file B; basically it's a ratio of words common between X and B to the number of words in X
- separating file weight calculation from aggregating across files would mean *two* read passes across dozens of GB, which I would like to avoid

---

(*) Or maybe `AWK` is not the best tool for such processing? If so, what alternative would you recommend?

Comment: You're running into a system limit (see `xargs --show-limits`). A Perl script could be passed the directory and use perl to read the directory and process each of the files.

Answer (score 1):

If the arguments are too many, you'll have to open and process the files yourself. With awk, without using any extensions you can use this (same idea as Jeff's answer):

```
awk '{ filename = $0; while(getline < filename > 0) { print $0; }}'
```

E.g., combine with a `find` command to find the files you need:

```
find /etc/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -444 -size 1 | \
  awk '{ filename = $0; while(getline < filename > 0) { print filename ":" $0; }}'
```

Further, depending on the version of awk, it is possible to push more files to be processed [as documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html#ARGC-and-ARGV).

> A program can alter ARGC and the elements of ARGV. Each time awk
>   reaches the end of an input file, it uses the next element of ARGV as
>   the name of the next input file. By storing a different string there,
>   a program can change which files are read. Use "-" to represent the
>   standard input. Storing additional elements and incrementing ARGC
>   causes additional files to be read.

To illustrate with an example:

```
find /etc/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -444 -size 1 | \
  awk '
    # When reading from STDIN, assume it is a list of files to read
    FILENAME == "-" { ARGV[ARGC] = $0; ARGC += 1 }
    # When not reading STDIN, it is a file to process
    FILENAME != "-" { print "---", FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0; }
    # These will run after every file, including STDIN, hence the check
    BEGINFILE { if (FILENAME != "-") { print ">>>", FILENAME; } }
    ENDFILE   { if (FILENAME != "-") { print "<<<", FILENAME, FNR, "lines"; } }'
```

Comment: 1. Is it a single AWK process for the entire file set?

Comment: 2. How traditional multiple blocks of per-line statements, with a pre-condition before each, should be restructured for this approach? Same question about gawk's BEGINFILE/ENDFILE blocks.

Comment: @wassrubleff, updated the answer to show how to do it with `BEGINFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

One option, if your filenames contain no quotes or whitespace, would be to pile them together with `cat`:

```
printf '%s ' * | xargs cat | awk ...
```

The above simply gets around the "argument list too long" error by using a builtin (`printf`) to print every filename, which is then sent to `xargs`, which breaks the filenames up into batches that it then sends to `cat`, the output of which is then sent to `awk`.

[But: don't use xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/365598/117549)

If you have GNU awk available (gawk) [at version 4.1 or above](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html), where dynamic module loading was introduced, it contains an extension that can read a directory itself, bypassing the problem.

Here's a sample gawk program that will open and read the files in whatever directory you pass to it; you then have to explicitly read from each file that you're interested in. The benefit is that you have a single (GNU) awk program that will read every file.

```
@load "readdir"
@load "filefuncs"

BEGIN { FS = "/" }
{
        result = stat($2, statdata)
        if (statdata["type"] != "file")
                next
        FS = " "
        while(getline < statdata["name"] > 0) {
                #print $1
        }
        FS = "/"
}
```

The script's main loop goes through every argument given on the command-line and attempts to open it as a directory. The resulting fields are:

- $1 = inode number
- $2 = file name
- $3 = type of file

We then use the filefuncs function `stat` to check the type of the file. If it is not a plain file, we skip it. Otherwise, we set `FS` back to the normal value and use `getline` to read through the file. After we're done with each file, we reset FS back to `/` so that it can split the next filename from `readdir`.

I learned about [gawk's readdir here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Readdir.html) and about [gawk's filefuncs stat here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-File-Functions.html).

Comment: 1. Do I understand correctly that xargs way gives a single concatenated "file" to AWK, leaving it up to AWK to detect file boundaries?

Comment: 2. How traditional multiple blocks of per-line statements, with a pre-condition before each, should be restructured for this approach? Same question about gawk's BEGINFILE/ENDFILE blocks.

Comment: Correct; awk would see one continuous input stream, with no file boundaries at all. If the files had internal markers, you could detect changes that way.

Comment: 2. You’d have to do your own pattern matching of lines inside the while loop; begin/end file would be immediately before and after that while loop.

Comment: 2: How do I iterate over lines of each file?

Comment: I iterate over the lines in the files with that inner while loop; the commented-out “print” statement would print field 1 from each line, as a demonstration.